# Strange Behaviour Seen After Reading Properties of ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, properties

So I am attempting to clone a `ListView` of mine such that I end up with a new `ListView` with the properties of the old one but without the items of the old one (whilst avoiding any referencing back to the old one).

```
private ListView generateEmptyClone(ListView toClone)
{
    ListView newCopy = new ListView();

    foreach (var propToClone in toClone.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = newCopy.GetType().GetProperty(propToClone.Name);
        if (propInfo.CanWrite && propInfo.Name != "TopItem") // TopItem causing problems
            propInfo.SetValue(newCopy, propToClone.GetValue(toClone, null));
    }

    foreach (ColumnHeader head in toClone.Columns)
    {
        newCopy.Columns.Add((ColumnHeader)head.Clone());
    }

    return newCopy;
}
```

The method above works perfectly fine, but when I go back to the original `ListView` and perform:

```
string[] customerToAdd = { "To IBT", customerName, contactNum, date, SKU, itemDescription,
                                             emp, emp, emp, emp, emp};
var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(customerToAdd);
listViewItem.Font = new Font(listViewItem.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
TableDisplay.Items.Insert(0, listViewItem);
```

I get the error:

> Exception:Thrown: "InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'." (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
>   A System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was thrown: "InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'."

So I created a method to compare the properties of the original `ListView` before and after I copied its properties and the only differences were that `CanSelect`, `Created` and `Visible` had changed from True to False.

Any ideas why it is behaving this way?

Comment: Can you provide the code used to create `myListViewItem`?

Comment: @jaredbaszler I have amended the post

Comment: I'm not seeing anything out of sorts here.  Maybe check that you have the same number of columns in the listview that you clone after you clone. Also, -1 is usually returned by some sort of find function when it can't find anything.  Such as if you are searching a ListBox or an array for an item and it doesn't find it.  If you are finding something and then trying to insert it at index of -1 that won't work.  Check your indexes throughout and make sure they are all valid.  That is fairly easy to debug.

Comment: @jaredbaszler I've checked and debugged everything. It is definitely something to do with the way that the properties are copied, specifically the first Foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I ended up just changing the method such that each property is set manually.

```
private ListView generateEmptyClone(ListView toClone)
{
    ListView newCopy = new ListView();

    newCopy.Alignment = ListViewAlignment.Top;
    newCopy.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    newCopy.BackgroundImageTiled = false;
    newCopy.Font = new Font("Mircosoft Sans Serif", 9F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)(0));
    newCopy.ForeColor = SystemColors.MenuText;
    // etc...


    foreach (ColumnHeader head in toClone.Columns)
    {
        newCopy.Columns.Add((ColumnHeader)head.Clone());
    }

    return newCopy;
}
```

Turns out that the bug only appeared when I disposed of the new copy later on in my application. So I believe that by iterating through the properties as I did in the original question, there must be a property with a reference back to the original `ListView` and so when the copy was disposed, some element of the original `ListView` was also disposed, hence the problems.